# Getting Connection refused for tcp connection SysLog Golang

Tags: ubuntu, go, tcp

I am using syslog on ubuntu 16.4 Operating System in golang to log error like following.

```
w, err = syslog.Dial("tcp", "localhost:2114", syslog.LOG_ERR, "testapi")
```

Here I'm getting following error.

dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2114: getsockopt: connection refused

I have already tried following things.

1. Enable port in firewall with - sudo ufw allow 2114 command.
2. Disable firewall and tried with that.
3. Tried other port with above steps.

Any help with will be really appreciated.

Here is the syslog.conf

```
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#           For more information see
#           /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html
#
#  Default logging rules can be found in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf


#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
#module(load="immark")  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception
#module(load="imudp")
#input(type="imudp" port="514")

# provides TCP syslog reception
#module(load="imtcp")
#input(type="imtcp" port="514")

# Enable non-kernel facility klog messages
$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on

##########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
##########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Filter duplicated messages
$RepeatedMsgReduction on

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

Comment: 2114 is a non-standard port, but syslog is usually udp rather than tcp excepting special config or tls.  Maybe syslog.Dial("udp", "localhost:2114", syslog.LOG_ERR, "testapi") ?  Unfortunately you will not get any err even if it not correct since udp is connectionless.

Comment: I have tried 5514 also but its not working!. What do you mean by non standard port?

Comment: You should post your syslog.conf

Comment: Can you check if any process is bound to 2114?

Comment: Added syslog.conf.

Comment: @Prabhu- I have checked with following command 'netstat -an|grep :2114' and nothing attached.

Comment: And hence you are getting the `connection refused` error. I think Tinwor's answer below should be correct one to address the issue.

Comment: @Prabhu- checking that only!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uncomment

```
#module(load="imtcp")
#input(type="imtcp" port="514")
```

To provide syslog TCP reception. Once you have do this restart the syslog service and will work.
If you want listen tcp on port `2114` you need to change the input as

```
input(type="imtcp" port="2114")
```

Comment: udp 514 is the default ?

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: Yes 514 UDP, 601 TCP and another one that I don't remember as TLS (6514)

Comment: @Tinwor - Getting same error dial tcp 127.0.0.1:514: getsockopt: connection refused. Should I use 601?

Comment: Well, if you want use as tcp yes, otherwise if you want use as ump use 514

Comment: Sorry, I haven't entirely ready your configuration file. Uncomment #module(load="imtcp") and #input(type="imtcp" port="514") and then restart syslog. Then try to connect using the tcp port on 514. If it works I need to update the answer